# different regex behavior when compiled

Tags: python, regex, py2exe

I'm staring at this for a while now, and hope I'm missing something obvious. Hopefully somebody will be able to point that out to me.
I'm using the following regex to look for filepaths in plaintext:

```
p = re.compile(r'(([A-Za-z]:[\\/])|(\.\.[\\/])+)([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+[\\/])+[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]+')
```

I know it's horrible, but it works. At least; when I'm running my python script. I need to compile to exe to have something self-contained, and I'm using the following for that:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import os

taggerData = [('nltk_data/taggers', ['C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/nltk_data/taggers/conll2000_aubt.pickle'])]

setup(
    console=[{'script': 'flurp.py'}],
    options={
        'py2exe': 
        {
            'bundle_files': 2,
            'includes': ['lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath'],
            'compressed': True,
            'excludes': ['_ssl'],
        }
    },
    zipfile = None,
    data_files=taggerData
)
```

Now when I have something like "C:\some\file\path\here.txt"; it do get a match when I run my python script. However, when I compile my script and then run, I don't get this same match. It will take me some time/work to produce a minimal script in order to reproduce exactly this, so basically I was just wondering if anyone has ever encountered similar problems, with regexes behaving differently when compiled (with py2exe (0.9.2.2))?

Comment: @jonsharpe Why do you feel the need to be rude?  The question is clear as it stands, and politely asked.  If you don't know the answer, as I don't, move on.

Comment: It would be nice if you include which version of py2exe you are using, and whether you have tried with a different version of py2exe

Comment: thanks for the tip, version added in the question

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting with my regex, it turned out that the following works:

```
p = re.compile(r'(([A-Za-z]:[\\/]+)|(\.\.[\\/]+)+)([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+[\\/]+)+[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]+')
```

With the only difference being the added + after my character class [\/] (e.g. backslash or forward slash). Not a brilliant solution, as it causes my regex to be less precise, but double escaping didn't help me either.

I hope this helps others having the same issue. But since my solution doesn't feel very decent, I'll leave the question open for other people to comment on/perhaps explain in a bit more detail what is going on here (or if it's just a known bug in py2exe?)